# Receive data remotely from autonomously working Arduino device

Tags: arduino

I want to receive data from the remote Arduino device. The device will measure voltage from multiple ADCs and send the data. There is no possibility to place the computer near the device. Since the distance is about 20 m, there should be as few wires as possible. What is the best way to do it: i2c, serial port, something else, and how to implement this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use serial communication that your Arduino libraries supports, I think one of the best options is [**RS485**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RS-485). It can be used up to 1200 meters which is crazy enough for Arduino projects (of course you have to add into the equation noise etc.).

**Advantages**:

1. RS485 is pretty resistant against noise because it uses twisted pair.
2. You can connect up to 32 devices.
3. It's also [cheap](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07B667STP).
4. It's used in real industry so you will get some valuable experience.

**Disadvantages**:

1. You need some bonus resistors (see in [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RS-485))
2. It doesn't have normalized connector.

Here is [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F34FJqS2OZ4) to what I achieved with RS485!

Comment: Agree. I would like to add: RS485 uses 3 wires (2 signals called A and B and a ground) and you only have to connect the serial port to the RS485 chip (and an extra port when sending data). No additional library needed.